# keep array keys while sorting 2D array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting

It's my 2D array:

```
$a = array(
    '6' => array(10, 5),
    '5' => array(20, 7),
    '40' => array(15, 9)
);
```

I can sort it simply with `array_multisort`:

```
foreach ($a as $k => $r) {
    $keys[$k] = $r[1]; 
}
array_multisort($keys, SORT_DESC, $a);
```

but it clears the keys ('6', '5', '40'):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 5
        )

)
```

Does `array_multisort` have any parameters to keep array keys?

Comment: Do you want to sort the keys? Like 40, 6, 5

Comment: @W.Kristianto: No, I want to sort the array. But I want to keep the keys also, and don't like to replace them by array numeric keys (start from 0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simpler solution using [`uasort`](http://php.net/uasort):

```
uasort($a, function ($a, $b) { return $a[1] - $b[1]; });
```

Comment: Thanks. but how can I change the sorting direction?

Comment: Switch the `$a` and `$b` arguments around.